# TCP, transfering files and folders but only folder seems to keep its file name

Tags: c#, tcp

im trying to create a way for the client to request a file or folder from the server and save it to their documents. So at the moment i have a tree view of all the servers files, the client can right click and receive a file or folder with the code below:

```
        if (isConnected())
        {
            if (selectedFile.Nodes.Count > 0) //If its a folder
            {
                consoleLog("Receiving folder (" + selectedFile.Text + ")... please wait");
                clientSendText("receiveFolder#" + selectedFile.FullPath.ToString() + "#", 1);
            }
            else //If its a file
            {
                consoleLog("Receiving file (" + selectedFile.Text + ")... please wait");
                clientSendText("receiveFile#" + selectedFile.FullPath.ToString() + "#", 1);
            }
        }
```

So that sends the command to receive either the file or folder, then server side it will run either one of the following commands depending on if its a file or folder

```
        public static void receiveFolder(string path)
    {
        path = getFullFolderPath(path);

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, path + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
            serverSendFile(path + ".zip", 8);

            if (File.Exists(path + ".zip"))
            {
                File.Delete(path + ".zip");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            serverSendText("Folder does not exist", 1);
        }
    }

    public static void receiveFile(string path)
    {
        path = getFullFilePath(path);

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            serverSendFile(path, 9);
        }
        else
        {
            serverSendText("File does not exist", 1);
        }
    }
```

So the way im sending a folder is zipping it first, then sending it as a file and deleting the zip folder after.

Just to note the 2nd parameter is the data type, so 8 is a zip and 9 is any file
The client the receives it like this:

```
                else if (dataType == 8)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        string savePath = Properties.Settings.Default.textSavePath;

                        consoleLog("Reply from server: folder receiving...please wait");

                        File.WriteAllBytes(savePath + ".zip", data);
                        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(savePath + ".zip", savePath);

                        if (File.Exists(savePath + ".zip"))
                        {
                            File.Delete(savePath + ".zip");
                        }

                        consoleLog("Folder saved to " + savePath);
                    }));
                }
                else if (dataType == 9)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        string savePath = Properties.Settings.Default.textSavePath;

                        consoleLog("Reply from server: file receiving...please wait");
                        File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, data);

                        consoleLog("File saved to " + savePath);
                    }));
                }
```

So receiving the folder works perfectly, the default save location is mydocuments so it sends there with the same name, unzips itself and i can view it like normal. Its the same with a regular file except it wont have a file name, i have to manually add "/picture.png" to the end of the save path in order for it to save, when it does it saves perfect and the image is intact but i have no idea why the folder keeps its name but the file doesnt. Is the file name sending with the data? am i missing something right in front of me, any advice will be helpful thankyou

Im also sending a file using the code below

```
    public static void serverSendFile(string filePath, byte dataType)
    {
        if (tcpServer != null)
        {
            if (tcpClient.Connected == true)
            {
                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                data = data.Concat(new byte[] { (byte)dataType }).ToArray();
                stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                int length = data.Length;
                byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
                datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
                stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: TCP isn't a file-transfer protocol. How are you sending and receiving the files?

Comment: I read all the bytes of the file and put it into a byte array, then concat the datatype and then sends it to the client, i should of added this is the code

Comment: Okay, so concat the filename as well. File names aren't part of file data, they're a value in the containing directory. Indeed, you can have one file with multiple names in different directories :)

Comment: ok im gonna try that, i was thinking to just put the file in a zip and send it like that so it keeps its file name but it seems abit unnessasery, ill try it your way

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a zip file you save it under the name ".zip" and then extract it. A Zip file contains information about file and folder names.

When you receive some other file you don't handle any information about the file name (do you even send it along with the content?)

You will need to combine the savePath and the file name and write the data to this file.

Comment: ohhh so the actual file im sending (the zip) doesnt have a name just like the file, but when im unzipping it, it then reveals the original folder name that was always stored in there. Would u say an easy way around this would just be to zip the single file i want so it would keep its name?